# Switch between Superfish and FlexNav depending on window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, superfish, matchmedia

I am trying to use 2 `jQuery` navigation scripts on one page (`Superfish` for desktops and `FlexNav`  for mobile). I am currently using `matchMedia` along with the `polyfill` by Paul Irish to respond to `CSS3` media query state changes within `JavaScript`.

The current code is only accomplishing 50% of the overall goal. If you access the web page initially with a window size equal to or greater than 999px wide then you get `Superfish` and if you initially access the web page with a window size less than 999px then you get `FlexNav`. The problem occurs when you resize the window above or below 999px as both scripts become active.

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 999px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}
// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({
            delay: 350,
            speed: 400,
        });
    } else {
        $("ul.flexnav").flexNav({
            'animationSpeed': '250',
            'transitionOpacity': true,
            'buttonSelector': '.menu-button',
            'hoverIntent': false
        });
    }
}
```

As much as I would like to get this working with `matchMedia`, I am open to all suggestions.

**Update: Thanks to Stephan's suggestion I now have the following code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // add destroy function for FlexNav
    flexNavDestroy = function () {
        $('.touch-button').off('touchstart click').remove();
        $('.item-with-ul *').off('focus');
    }
    // media query event handler
    if (matchMedia) {
        var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 999px)");
        mq.addListener(WidthChange);
        WidthChange(mq);
    }
    // media query change

    function WidthChange(mq) {
        if (mq.matches) {
            if (typeof (flexNav) != "undefined") {
                flexNavDestroy();
            }
            superfish = $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({
                delay: 350,
                speed: 400,
            });
        } else {
            if (typeof (superfish) != "undefined") {
                superfish.superfish('destroy');
            }
            flexNav = $("ul.flexnav").flexNav({
                'animationSpeed': '250',
                'transitionOpacity': true,
                'buttonSelector': '.menu-button',
                'hoverIntent': false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Remaining Issue:**
The destroy function for `FlexNav` is only partially destroying it.

Answer (score 5):

The best way would probably be to destroy the other plugin when you're activating one.

If I look in the source of [Superfish](https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish/blob/master/src/js/superfish.js) there is a destroy function which does this, but flexNav doesn't have such a function. You can create one though:

```
flexNavDestroy = function(){
    $('.touch-button').off('touchstart click').remove();
    $(('.item-with-ul *').off('focus');
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        if(typeof(flexNav) != "undefined") {
            flexNavDestroy();
        }

        superfish = $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({
            delay: 350,
            speed: 400,
        });
    } else {
        if(typeof(superfish) != "undefined") {
            superfish.superfish('destroy'); 
        }

        flexNav = $("ul.flexnav").flexNav({
            'animationSpeed': '250',
            'transitionOpacity': true,
            'buttonSelector': '.menu-button',
            'hoverIntent': false
        });
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***
I've looked a little bit more into FlexNav, and there's a few things I missed.

I think the styles are colliding because FlexNav sets a lot of styles by default. We can easily prevent that by using two classes: One for flexnav styling (the default `.flexnav`) that we can remove to hide all it's styles, and one for binding the javascript function (that will always stay there, or we can't re-attach it).

I generally like to prepend any classes that are meant as JS hooks with `js-`, so in my example (below) I replaces the `.flexnav` class on the menu with `.js-flexnav`. Then to activate flexnav you have to add this line just before you call `$('ul.flexnav').flexNav()`

```
$('.js-flexnav').addClass('flexnav');
```

In the destroy function you will have to remove the class again, which I will show shortly.

In addition, I'm not sure how Superfish does the showing and hiding, but since FlexNav collapses all submenus, it's also safe to say you should re-show them so that Superfish can do it's own thing.

The updated destroy function to reflect this:

```
function flexNavDestroy(){
    $('.touch-button').off('touchstart click').remove();
    $('.item-with-ul *').off('focus');
    $('.js-flexnav').removeClass('flexnav').find('ul').show(); // removes .flexnav for styling, then shows all children ul's
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle that shows activating/deactivating flexNav with the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/9HndJ/

Let me know if this does the trick for you!

Comment: Using the destroy functions definitely improves the issue, the only problem that persists is Superfish not initializing after a window resize.

Comment: Found an extra left parenthesis in the destroy function that was causing the Superfish problem. However, the destroy function only partially destroys FlexNav.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of. I didn't install FlexNav, I wrote the function by looking at the source code and trying to undo all the binds that were in there. I'll try to make some time to see if I can help you out a bit more tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

here is an alternative path :

once page is loaded :

cache the menu in a jquery object, clone it  **& instantiate both plugin** one on each clone

```
$menucontainer= $("#menu_container");
$memufish = $menucontainer.find(".menu");
$menuflex=$menufish.clone();

$menufish.superfish().detach();
$menuflex.prependTo($menucontainer).flexnav().detach();
```

(they are loaded anyway so it's no big deal even if most of the time one won't be needed, it will be there & ready just in case - however test if you can instantiate on the clone without appending it to the DOM)

depending on width append / prepend the required one

```
$menuflex.prependTo($menucontainer);
```

on change width detach one reattach the other

```
$menufish.detach();
$menuflex.prependTo($menucontainer);
```

you could also work your way checking if plugin was instantiated on a width change (in order to not instantiate uselessly onload) but in any way I believe the use of `clone()` and `detach()` are very much adapted to solve easily your problem. The destroy way seems to be a hassle, lots of work (for the script as well when some user is raving with window resize) loss of time & a risk of many bugs to me ( expect more and more lag at every destroy re instantiate - with `detach()` no worries)

cons : will use a bit more memory overhaul

pros :

- script will work less & it will be real fast to switch from one to the other
- you could make a plugin from this and add other menu plugin to your app very easily without worry about conflict and how to destroy

Comment: nb : note that `detach()` remove the object from the dom but keeps it in jquery cache along with all associated handlers

Comment: That's quite an elegant solution, nice.